# ChessDB databases import

Tags: opening, analysis, software, endgame, open-source

I've just installed the ChessDB software hosted at SourceForge. While discovering the software I see that the databases that come with the software are empty  and I would like to know how to import new databases of openings or endgames,...etc.
Any help greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He (author) explains how to go about getting this [here](http://chessdb.sourceforge.net/Scid/). The sourceforge game databases are available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chessdb/files/databases%20of%20games/)

**Update:**
 To go about downloading the database from the second sourceforge link provided above, the author provides instructions [here](http://chessdb.sourceforge.net/tutorial/download_a_database.php) (can do it directly form ChessDB's *Tools* menu).

Comment: Thank you @shivsky, But I see that there is not enough detail on how to install the ChessDB databases after downloading them from the link you provided here : http://sourceforge.net/projects/chessdb/files/databases%20of%20games/