# Issues downloading the latest version of chess database on chessdb!

Tags: database, pgn

I downloaded the lastest version of [chessdb](http://chessdb.sourceforge.net/) but while trying to download the large database (about 3.5M games), I have got errors and the download does not start.
I deactivated my firewall and my antivirus but the problem is still there.

The errors are shown in these 2 screenshots:

- http://i59.tinypic.com/2whl6k6.png
- http://i62.tinypic.com/oji0lj.png

Has anyone else experienced the same problem?

Comment: I don't think the URL is valid anymore.

Comment: Did you check this http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/chessdb-databases-import ?